# Path-Connectedness of Union

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Can I have a hint to prove that $A \cup B$ is not path-connected, where $A = \{(x,y):0 \le x \le 1, y = x/n \text{ for n} \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $B = \{(x,y):1/2 \le x \le 1, y = 0 \}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $p$ is a path from $(0,0)$ to some point in $B$. As $B$ is closed, we can assume that $p$ doesn't intersect $B$ until the end where $p(1)=:b\in B$. There is a connected neighborhood $U$ around $1\in I$ such that $p[U]\subseteq A\setminus\{(0,0)\}\cup B$. But then $p[U\setminus\{1\}]\subset A\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ which is not connected.

You can think of $A\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ as a topological sum of lines 
$$A_n=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x\le1, y=x/n \}$$
Since $p[U\setminus\{1\}]$ is connected, it must be contained in some $A_n$. But $p(1)\in B$. Can you reach a contradiction?

Comment: Why does $p[U \setminus \{1\}] \subset A \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ imply a contradiction? (I understand that $p[U \setminus \{1\}]$ is connected.)  Also why is $A \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ not connected?

Comment: Can anyone provide a reason?

Comment: @Jonny: I extended my answer.

Comment: I am trying to find a separation of $p[U]$, but I am not succeeding.  Clearly $p(1)$ is closed in $p[U]$, but I can't see that $p[U \setminus \{1\}]$ is also.  The difficulty is finding a suitable closed subset of $R^2$ to intersect $p[U]$ with.

Comment: @Jonny: You only have to show that $p(1)$ is not in the closure of $A_n$. But the closure of $A_n$ is just $A_n\cup\{(0,0)\}.$ This then contradicts the the continuity of $p$ since $1\in\overline{U\setminus\{1\}}$.

Comment: Are there not points on the positive x-axis that are limit points of the union of all such $A_n$?  Indeed, those lines get arbitrarily close to the positive x-axis, so it seems that $p(1)$ is in the closure of the $A_n$ wrt $X$.

Comment: @Jonny: But it is not in the closure of a single $A_n$.

Comment: Ok, so I think what I don't understand is why $p[U \setminus \{1\}]$ must lie in a single $A_n$.  I can see why it cannot lie in finitely many $A_n$ (because I can prove the disconnectedness of finitely many $A_n$.) But what about an infinite union of such $A_n$?  Why is such a union disconnected?

Comment: @Jonny: In $A∖\{(0,0)\}=\bigcup A_n$ every $A_n$ is open. It is the intersection with $$\left\{(x,y)\mid 0<x, \frac x{n+1}<y<\frac x{n-1}\right\}$$